# Word meaning "find the truth of"?

Tags: single-word-requests

The closest word I could think of was *quest* or *journey*. But I think they don't imply a "search for truth". Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

> Now I had the strength to continue [...] about UFO's.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for something other than "investigate"?

Comment: @Oldbag Oh, you're right. That's a good word. I'm just wondering if there's something closer to quest.

Comment: Simply _research_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I had the strength to continue **pursuing the facts** about UFOs.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase *uncover the truth* suggests a quest for something hidden or elusive.  *Merriam-Webster* offers this definition and example for *[uncover](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uncover)*

> to make known :  bring to light :  disclose, reveal: *uncover the truth*

Similarly, *seek out the truth*.

Comment: Wow, how did you do that? Post the same answer twice?

Comment: @janoChen By mistake, I think: re-post instead of edit. Now rectified.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thank you. Multiple open windows and new Mac navigation still befuddle me at times.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I had the strength **to carry on my research** about UFO's.

Answer (score 0):

The [word](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/verify?s=t) I would use is **verify.**

Comment: Verify would mean to confirm the truth, not to find it.

Answer (score 0):

*Detective work* or *sleuth work* (I've also heard *sleuthery*, though this doesn't appear to be formally defined anywhere) all describe the process of investigating a mystery. Similarly, *demystify* describes the process of uncovering a mystery.

Comment: You can also say *sleuthing*. See the examples [here.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sleuth)

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I think I would prefer ***identify the truth*** in contrast to the term **UFO**.

And, depending on context, you could possibly use the expression ***ferret out the truth***, too.  But, the closest I can think of that partially incorporates the idea of truth into the word, would be ***discover***.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

[Suss](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suss) is a verb meaning to discover or figure out (M-W) - that may be what is sought here.